# Why doesn't the relative path work?

Tags: c++, xcode, sdl

I am trying a SDL project in Xcode 4.6. I followed the instructions at [HERE](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/mac/xcode/index.php) and everything went fine. I even ran the test code there.

Now when I try to load a BMP

```
SDL_Surface* bmp = SDL_LoadBMP("cb.bmp");
```

It says Unable to load the bmp. But if I use the **Absoulte path**, it works fine.

What is the problem? What should I do to use the relative path?

The folder structure is as follows:

```
sdl_test
    sdl_test.xcodeproj
    sdl_test
        cb.bmp
        SDLMain.m
        SDLMain.h
        main.cpp
        sdl_test.1
```

Comment: Make sure the bitmap is in the current working directory.

Comment: Yes the bitmap is alongside the main.cpp.

Comment: @Captain Obvlious: I have added the directory structure of the project

Comment: Is your executable in the "sdl_test" directory, or some other directory nearby? I find most IDE's put object files and executables in a directory called "debug" or "release", in a directory parallel to or a directory under the source code.

Comment: It is at location:
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sdl_test-fsjktcexwmjuhrdysrlybvcenghe/Build/Products/Debug/sdl_test

Comment: Just put cb.bmp in every possible folder (usually project folder and debug/release folder) and see that's loaded then start to delete it one by one while trying to load it and eventually you will find the place.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this exact same problem when I started out with Xcode.

You have to change the working directoy in the SDLMain.m file. Find the setupWorkingDirectory method, and replace it with this:

```
/* Set the working directory to the .app's parent directory */
- (void) setupWorkingDirectory:(BOOL)shouldChdir
{ 
    //setting the working directoy to MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/  
    NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] changeCurrentDirectoryPath:resourcePath];

}
```

Hope this works.